# Why not use static methods for CBV's?

Tags: django, oop, django-rest-framework

Pycharm was suggesting that I make my CBV methods static, and I thought "why not". But there's got to be a reason that this isn't done, otherwise a lot of people smarter than myself must've thought to do this before. Now I'm trying to understand why it isn't done.

I read the tutorial in the documentation again, and the only place `self` is used is to refer to the objects methods, which themselves could be static. So I still don't see any reason that they shouldn't be all made static.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

I tried making them static in my project, and it seemed to work without any issue. So would someone please explain to me why these methods are not made static as a common practice? FBV's are static, so CBV's should very well be using staticmethods as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

They are not static because it is easier to work with instance of a view. Usually when you are writing staticmethod you are just bounding function to class/instance for easier usage. This function doesn't know about instance itself. It is here just for namespacing purposes.

But in CBV data like `request`, `object` etc is stored on `self`, so that it can be accessed in any of the instance methods, without chain passing them through all method calls. Don't forget that there are many underlaying methods for working with form, context, template etc. And you may need to have shared "instance context" for them to do what you want.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is syntactic sugar and can very well be static if wanted, correct? Does this apply for Django Rest Framework views as well? I'm still looking for valid usage cases, I was only able to find an obfuscated example that looks like they use instance variables for the sake of using them: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Comment: @DavidTan what do you mean by saying syntactic sugar?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I don't think this answer is correct. `request` is passed by `dispatch` into the mapped view. I don't see any reason not to decorate with `@staticmethod`. I think it's more explicit which is more aligned with Python's philosophy.